# How to best deal with <img> size when displaying HTML inside smaller viewports

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am rendering HTMLs fetched from external sources onto to a Bootstrap modal dialog box with class set as `modal-dialog modal-lg`.

The `<img>` tags are always a problem, where images most often overflow the modal due to their size.

What is the best way to resize the image tag?  Would replacing the `<img>` tags' size with a PHP's `preg_replace()` be possible?

I had taken the long route of generating thumbnails, but that didn't work too well for some images.

Comment: Probably, yes, resizing the image to avoid the overflow it's the right thing to do. Show up a resized image with a link to the original one, showed outside any modal panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to keep the images responsive is the following:

```
img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you even directly use inbuilt classes of bootstrap i.e.

```
<img src="" class="img img-responsive" alt="">
```

these will take care of everything.
you need not to write any other code to make it responisve.

thanks